# Access sessionFactory using Jboss Jndi lookup e.g. java:/hibernate/SessionFactory

Tags: hibernate, maven, jboss7.x, sessionfactory

I'm trying to access sessionFactory using Jboss7.1.1.Final Jndi lookup under maven.

While deploying it I'm getting in log following

```
17:28:33,670 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
17:28:33,671 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
17:28:34,026 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Configured SessionFactory: java:/hibernate/SessionFactory

17:28:35,785 INFO  [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) building session factory
17:28:36,535 INFO  [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Factory name: java:/hibernate/SessionFactory
17:28:36,537 INFO  [org.hibernate.util.NamingHelper] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) JNDI InitialContext properties:{}

17:28:36,546 INFO  [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Bound factory to JNDI name: java:/hibernate/SessionFactory
```

Now at time of casting using following code

```
Context ctx1=new InitialContext();
Object obj1=ctx1.lookup("java:/hibernate/SessionFactory");
SessionFactoryImpl sess= (SessionFactoryImpl)obj1;
```

I'm getting exception as follows

```
17:28:36,691 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl cannot be cast to org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl
```

Dependency I'm using for this is

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
<version>4.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

and my xml is

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory name="java:/hibernate/SessionFactory">
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/DUMY</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.username">postgres</property>
    <property name="connection.password">postgres</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>        

    <property name="hibernate.session_factory_name">java:/hibernate/SessionFactory</property>          
    .
    .
    .

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

I made it working bu putting whole Database accessing logic inside stateless session bean and it worked fine for me :)